# Search SQL table for names?

Tags: php, sql, search

I am writing a search engine for my site. In the users table there is first and last. I would like to find either a first or last name that matches the string in $search. I would like to output links with the results. I am not asking for you to write any code just put me in the right direction. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

From the SQL point of view, yes it is possible. And the query could be :

```
select link from users where firstname like '%searchstring%' or lastname like '%searchstring%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a search engine you might want to look at the full-text search capabilities of your database.  Full-text searching offers more advanced features than basic SQL.

[SQL server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

[Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/content.htm)

[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html)

[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)